# Is there any guideline of when to use IBEA and NSGAII?

Tags: optimization

I am aware that IBEA and NSGAII are using different metrics for evolution and mutation, is there any guideline on when to use each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the shape of solution space. If you suspect the solution concentrate on one portion, IBEA is a good choice, but if you suspect that they are distributed, then NSGA-II is a good choice. The reason is that NSGA-II have this assumption by adding a crowding distance, so that it try to explore different region if possible.